# Move factory apps and services to SD card in Android 5

Tags: applications, google-play-store, storage, google-play-services, internal-sd

I've got this non-rooted [BLU Energy Diamond](https://www.gsmarena.com/blu_energy_diamond_mini-8189.php) with an absurdly long lasting battery that I use at work for testing apps on old devices, however, it only has 4GB of internal memory and a 16GB SD card.

As we all know, **Google** absolutely forbids moving its apps and services to the SD card, while endlessly increasing their sizes for no reason, in an effort to render all phones obsolete as fast as possible. **The minute I enable Play Store + Play Services, internal memory is maxed out, without a single third-party app installed nor updated.**

[image]

Manufacturers only allow bloatware uninstallation after facing lawsuits [like this](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_lets_users_delete_preinstalled_apps_in_china_in_light_of_lawsuit-blog-13348.php) in China. I managed to remove bloatware without a lawsuit by using  the [adb shell](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/), however, this is not nearly enough. Is there any hope of effectively **moving Chrome, Webview, Play Store, Play Services and all to SD card**? I don't care if there's a risk of rendering them useless, because as is, the phone is already useless if nothing can be installed when Play Services is enabled.

I understand there was a **hack to use SD card as internal memory** on phones without that option, but I'm not sure if this was ever available to Android 5 or if requires a rooted device.

Comment: Hi, this site is not a forum. Please remove the rsnts and adk s clear single question. By the way, your assumptions ate faulty. For starters, Google doesn't write most of the apps.

Comment: Find a ROM with no Google stuff (example:LineageOS or any that is still supported for you device), root your phone, install that ROM and move your apps to ext. SD// For a phone of that vintage you'd need to search for all these steps on your own.. XDA is a good starting place

Comment: @beeshyams thanks I will certainly try that, you could have posted it as a reply because it's a reasonable answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks but it's at best a suggestion for me unless I tried it. Once you try and succeed you can make that into a far better answer that would help others! Ping me for an upvote when you do so!